# count of entity of objects symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I ve got two tables. 1- property 2-type. each property has a type. in my filter form i want to display the types in checkboxes and beside the count of how many properties are of a certain type.

this is my query in my repository:

```
public function countByType($type){
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('count(p.id)')
            ->where('p.type = :type')
            ->setParameter('type', $type)
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
    }
```

the code in my controller:

```
$typeID = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Type::class)->findAll();
        foreach ($typeID as $tID){
            $propertyCountByType = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Property::class)->countByType($tID);
        }
```

so what I am trying to do is passing the type id in a loop to the query to give me the count. this code is showing only the count of the last type in the table.

Comment: You want the total count?

Comment: How exactly do you store the result? Do you use that single variable for all types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwritting `$propertyCountByType` at each iteration, that's why you are getting only the last value.

If you want to store each count **separately**, you can store the values in an array

```
$typeID = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Type::class)->findAll();
$propertyCountByType = array();
foreach ($typeID as $tID) {
    $propertyCountByType[] = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Property::class)->countByType($tID);
    //                  ^------------ add the current result to the array
}
```

That array can be indexed on the `$tID` this way, in the loop :

```
$propertyCountByType[$tID] = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Property::class)->countByType($tID);
```

---

Or, even better, do that in a single query, using a group by

```
public function countByType(){
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                ->select('count(p.id) AS CountByType', 'p.type AS type') // each row will contain the count and the type
                ->groupBy('p.type')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getArrayResult(); // get the result as array
}
```